# Event delegation working for dynamically added button but not for the dynamically added menu attached to it

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I'm loading a button and a menu attached to it dynamically depending on the screen size, the loading works and everything but when I'm trying to delegate a click event for one of the list items in the menu it's not working. I find this odd since the delegation of the button works perfect.. I have the button in a seperate PHP file and the menu in another PHP file and load them via an AJAX call.

This is the button:

```
<button id="mobile-nav-btn"><img src="img/threestripes.png"></button>
```

And this is the menu that slides in when u click the button:

```
<div id="mobile-nav-container">
    <nav>
        <ul id="mobile-main-nav">
            <li class="main-nav-items nav-items"><a href="index.php">Startsida</a></li>
#services --> <li id="services" class="main-nav-items nav-items" data-toggle="dropdown"><a href="#">Tjänster</a>
                <ul class="sub-nav-menu">
                    <li class="sub-nav-items"><a href="#">Fransar</a></li>
                    <li class="sub-nav-items"><a href="#">Hår</a></li>
                    <li class="sub-nav-items"><a href="#">Sminkning</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="main-nav-items nav-items"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav-items nav-items"><a href="#">Boka tid</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav-items nav-items"><a href="#">Prislista</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Delegating the button (works):

```
$('#main-nav-container').on('click', '#mobile-nav-btn', function() {

    if ($('#mobile-nav-container').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#mobile-nav-container').stop().show().animate({left: 0}, 'slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#mobile-nav-container').stop().animate({left: -150}, 'slow', function() {
            $('#mobile-nav-container').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Delegating the services list item, which doesn't work:

```
$('#mobile-main-nav').on('click', '#services', function() {
    $('#services ul').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

The `#mobile-main-nav` has a `display: none;` when it gets loaded, I don't know if that has anything to do with it but it really shouldn't. I'm stumped why this isn't working so if anyone of you might know then let me know.

Comment: Cad you create a jsfiddle to debug faster?

Comment: @Alin I don't think it would work in a fiddle since I use php includes, right?

Comment: You can, just need to add the html contents in the fiddle, anyway, you have before the services a #services --> , that is wrong, may interfere with your code, maybe you wanted to write <!-- #services -->

Comment: I added that here, I don't have it in my original code.

Comment: @Alin Thing is it works when you just add the HTML directly but not when getting the HTML via ajax. It doesn't make sense since the button delegation works and it gets added the same way.

Comment: Hmm...that's kinda weird, I'll give you that..